# Prefetch API calls with service worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, service-worker-config

I have setup service worker for my angular app. The caching of the data groups works fine as long as the relevant page that the API call is made is visited. However my goal is to on the load of the application cache the data of all the endpoints specified in the ngsw-config. Tried using the example provided for swUpdate that is :

```
swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
      swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    });
```

on the start of the application in the constructor of my appcomponent, but no luck. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

it need to download metadata from server try as follow

```js
    swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
      swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    });
    if(swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      swUpdate.checkForUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: added the snippet as shown, still same behavior. Only the APIs that are called get cached the rest of the ones are still not. Do i need to have some dummy calls at the start just so that the results get cached ?

Comment: @Clueless is `swUpdate.isEnabled` true? and did you see any request to `ngsw.json` in network view?

Comment: Yes it is true, also there are many fetch calls to ngsw-worker.js, nothing related to the APIs not in this page.

Comment: came across this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613883/angular-6-service-worker-datagroups-not-working> which says that I have to make the HTTP calls, in this case since I am not is that the problem. Angular wont in any case automatically call the URLs in the datagroup i assume :(